# Is there a way to speed up Rake on cygwin?

Tags: ruby, performance, rubygems, rake

I am a complete newcomer to anything Ruby-related, but I am trying to get acquainted with Ceedling for use in unit testing embedded C code.  I am using cygwin for both gcc and ruby on a Windows 7 machine, and I am experiencing some painfully slow execution times for rake.  I am getting 6+ second delays even for "rake version":

```
~/projectDir $ time rake version
...
real    0m6.464s
user    0m0.468s
sys     0m2.324s
```

But outside of my project directory this curiously changes to a more reasonable time:

```
~/notProjectDir $ time rake version
...
real    0m1.513s
user    0m0.124s
sys     0m0.436s
```

For comparison, "ruby -v" doesn't even take a tenth of a second.  Also, it appears that rake/ceedling runs quite fast once it is started, but I end up waiting 6 seconds or more to then see it generate all of my test outputs nearly instantly.

Some Googling tells me that I should expect a performance hit when using gems, but this seems a bit long for me believe it is normal.  Is there anything I can/should do in my path to help with the gem-loading process?  I have attempted to bypass the initial lookup phase by the following, to no avail:

```
time ruby -I /usr/share/gems/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/ \
             /usr/share/gems/gems/rake-10.4.2/bin/rake version
...
real    0m6.706s
user    0m0.451s
sys     0m2.371s
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: `Rake.application.run` (the command called when calling `rake`) loads the Rakefile in the current directory. This would be my assumption as to why it takes so much longer inside a project directory rather than outside as it needs to load up all rake tasks available. [`Rake::Application#run`](https://github.com/ruby/rake/blob/master/lib/rake/application.rb#L76)

Comment: @engineersmnky So is 6 seconds normal for this kind of task?  Is there a way to keep these loaded so that subsequent calls don't take as long?

Comment: Are you building and running your code and in cygwin? If not I would I wouldn't use it. ``msys`` is smaller and faster. Otherwise try installing Ruby from http://rubyinstaller.org/

Comment: Did you every find a solution? I am having the same problem except sometimes it seems faster then it gets really sluggish other times. It is really bad on one computer but not so bad on others. Very strange. I run from the MINGW64 used by git bash.

Comment: @bd2357 - No, unless you count moving to the Windows Subsystem for Linux as a solution.  My best theory for why it was slow was that our Avecto Defendpoint security software (or our antivirus) was slowing down every fork/process creation.  Defendpoint in particular is very taxing on the system performance.It could have also been related to the path